# How to do a continuous mysql insert using foreach?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert multiple urls(url_array) into the database.

First, I need to get some information from the urls ( url title, url images,...decsription). I am doing this using SimpleHtmlDom.

So I placing this in a foreach loop. My hope is that it inserts after each iteration until the end of the array.

If there is a bad url, it should skip to the next url in the array.

I also want that at the end( the last iteration) some json success message is parse back through jquery.

For the code I have below, it only inserts sometimes just 2 or 3 of which there are still more urls in the array.

Here is my code :

```
 $txturls = $_POST['bulkurls'];
          $urlsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $txturls));
          //var_dump($urlsArray);
          $i = 0;
          $len = count($urlsArray);
          foreach($urlsArray as $url){
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            if ($result !== false) 
            {
              $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
              if ($statusCode == 404) 
              {
                $checkExist = "URL Not Exists";
              }
              else
              {
                 $checkExist = "URL Exists";
              } 
            }
            else
            {
              $checkExist = "URL not Exists";
            }
        if($checkExist === "URL Exists"){

         $html = SimpleHtmlDom::file_get_html($url);
            foreach($html->find('title') as $element) 
            {
                 $urltitle = $element->plaintext;
            }
            $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
            $description = $tags['description']; 
            if(strlen($description) < 1){$description = $urltitle .' '.'check title';};
                    $images = array();
        foreach($html->find('meta[property=og:image]') as $element) {
         if(!preg_match('/blank.(.*)/i', $element->content) && filter_var($element->content, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            {
            $images[] = url_to_absolute($linkurl, $element->content);
            }

        }

        foreach ($images as $ext){
            //$imagesize = getimagesize(''.$ext.'');
            if (pathinfo($ext, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
            $image = "<img src=\"$ext\" alt=\"$urltitle\">";
            break;
        }
        }

    $linkurl = $url;
    $checkIfUrlExist = $this->_modellinks->checkUrlExist($linkurl);
        if($checkIfUrlExist == false){
    $this->_modellinks->addBulkLinks($data['log_username'], $ipaddress, $linkurl, $urltitle, $subafrolinks, $keywords, $description, $image);

        }
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == $len - 1) {
    // last
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thanks for your submission! Your URL has been submitted successfully  And its under review . <strong>You will be notified when your post is published online. This usually takes less than 1 hour.<br> Here is your preview link'));
            die($output);
}
$i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is inserting 2-3 URLs, it implies that your insertion query as well as foreach loop are working well.

When you say that there are still more URLs left in the array, are you talking about $urlsArray ?

Have you checked whether flag '$checkExists' is set for remaining URLs? 
To do that try pushing these URLs where $checkExists == 'URL Exists' in a new array $arGoodUrl and then work on it. You'll get a better idea then.

Comment: I understand what you mean. And yes maybe I should do a pre  check of the urls to get which exist.